# What are the base Line of Sight values for units in Age of Empires 2?

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-the-age-of-kings

I've been searching the internet for [a chart](http://aoe2.unitstatistics.com/unit-database) or even a wiki with either [compiled unit info](http://gaming.wikia.com/wiki/Age_of_Empires_II_military_units) or [various individual information about units](http://ageofempires.wikia.com/wiki/Militia_%28Age_of_Empires_II%29) in AoE2 (either AoK or AoC expansion, preferably the latter) that gives the basic number of tiles the unit can see assuming all things being equal (flat ground, no upgrades).

I have found nothing so far.

While [various technology upgrades](http://ageofempires.wikia.com/wiki/Technology_%28Age_of_Empires_II%29) mention +2, +4, etc. LOS to buildings or units, I cannot find anything that is telling me the base value to begin with for the various units. A Scout has more than a Villager, etc., but not hard numbers.

I would like to know if anyone is aware of a resource for this, or has done a unit by unit study themselves (I prefer not to embark on such a study myself if information already exists).

The best answer for me would be an actual listing here of the LOS values for units (including Age of Conquerors expansion), and if copied from information from another web source, the link to that as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a link to a site I found using my Google Fu - http://homepage.ntlworld.com/walbanger/Pages/AoCUnitStatsNoneCable.htm

It lists the LOS of all units in the game and is updated till the 1.0c patch.

**UPDATE - Values from the Link (as of 1-17-2014)**

(I've included the compiled values from your link in your answer to make it link independent -- ScottS.)

```
Unit Type              LOS
```

```
BARRACKS UNITS
Militia                 4
Man-at-Arms             4
Long Swordsman          4
Two-handed Swordsman    5
Champion                5
Spearman                4
Pikeman                 4
Halberdier              4
Eagle Warrior           6
Elite Eagle Warrior     8

ARCHERY RANGE UNITS
Archer                  6
Crossbowman             7
Arbalest                7
Cavalry Archer          5
Heavy Cavalry Archer    6
Hand Cannoneer          9
Skirmisher              6
Elite Skirmisher        7

STABLE UNITS
Scout Cavalry           4
Light Cavalry           4
Hussar                  4
Knight                  4
Cavalier                4
Paladin                 5
Camel                   4
Heavy Camel             5

SIEGE WORKSHOP UNITS
Mangonel                9
Onager                  10
Siege Onager            10
Scorpion                9
Heavy Scorpion          9
Battering Ram           3
Capped Ram              3
Siege Ram               3
Bombard Cannon          14

CASTLE UNITS
Trebuchet (packed/not)  18
Petard                  4
Berserk                 3
Elite Berserk           5
Cataphract              4
Elite Cataphract        5
Chu Ko Nu               6
Elite Chu Ko Nu         6
Conquistador            8
Elite Conquistador      8
Huskarl                 3
Elite Huskarl           5
Jaguar Warrior          3
Elite Jaguar Warrior    5
Janissary               10
Elite Janissary         10
Longbowman              7
Elite Longbowman        8
Mameluke                5
Elite Mameluke          5
Mangudai                6
Elite Mangudai          6
Plumed Archer           6
Elite Plumed Archer     7
Samurai                 4
Elite Samurai           5
Tarkan                  4
Elite Tarkan            5
Teutonic Knight         3
Elite Teutonic Knight   5
Throwing Axeman         5
Elite Throwing Axeman   6
War Elephant            4
Elite War Elephant      5
War Wagon               6
Elite War Wagon         7
Woad Raider             3
Elite Woad Raider       5

DOCK UNITS
Fishing Ship            5
Trade Cog               6
Transport Ship          5
Galley                  7
War Galley              8 
Galleon                 9 
Fire Ship               5
Fast Fire Ship          6
Demolition Ship         6
Heavy Demolition Ship   5
Cannon Galleon          15
Elite Cannon Galleon    17
Longboat                8
Elite Longboat          9
Turtle Ship             8
Elite Turtle Ship       8

TOWN CENTER/MONASTERY/MARKET UNITS
Villager                4
Monk                    11
Missionary              9
Trade Cart              6
```

---

For completeness, here are structure values also.

---

```
Structure Type         LOS
```

```
BUILDINGS
Barracks                5
Dock                    5
Farm                    0
House                   1
Lumber Camp             5
Mill                    5
Mining Camp             5
Archery Range           5
Blacksmith              5
Fish Trap               1
Market                  4
Stable                  5
Castle                  8
Monastery               5
Siege Workshop          4
Town Center             7
University              4
Wonder                  6

TOWERS/WALLS/GATES
Outpost                 5
Watch Tower             10
Guard Tower             10
Keep                    10
Bombard Tower           10
Palisade Wall           2
Stone Wall              2
Fortified Wall          2
Gate                    5
```

---

These are base values. Civilization, age advancement, and technology bonuses are not considered here.

Comment: I've submitted an update to your answer with the complied values from your link source. That was a good link -- thanks for providing. Also, [here was another link I found after your posting that spoke of LOS](http://aok.heavengames.com/cgi-bin/forums/display.cgi?action=ct&f=3,37771,2310,all)

Comment: @ScottS - Great work!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I don't know of an already compiled list of Line of Sight attributes.

However, the LoS value can be viewed using a unit editor. The only one I know of is the [Advanced Genie Editor 3](http://aok.heavengames.com/blacksmith/showfile.php?fileid=11002). The editor is fairly complex and will probably be quite scary to view at first. I've not really used it that extensively, so can't comment very much on it.

The editor has the power to edit nearly everything in game. Understandably, if used in the wrong way, you can break the game, so it is always best to back up the files that it will change before doing so. In your case, it is probably irrelevant as you will likely just view the LoS attribute.

[image: Example of LoS attribute in the editor]

The image shows the Line of Sight attribute for the Archer. A more user friendly name is available at the top of the right hand pane, so identifying the correct unit isn't too difficult (I'm scrolled down quite a bit in the screenshot).

This will obviously take quite a bit to pull together, so I can understand if you just forget about this. If you do decide to do it, I think the AoE community would be very grateful if you published it.

Maybe someone else will come up with an easier solution.

Comment: Thanks for the useful info. Using such an editor would at least be better than creating units and visually determining the radius. I am still hopeful that someone has done this already, but if not, this is at least a viable alternative should I choose to do it myself. And yes, if I did do it myself, at the very least I would post it as an answer to this question.